# Ruby search for match in large json

Tags: json, ruby, regex, search, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a pretty huge json file of short lines from a screenplay. I am trying to match keywords to keywords in the json file so I can pull out a line from the json.

The json file structure is like this:

```
[
 "Yeah, well I wasn't looking for a long term relationship. I was on TV. ",
 "Ok, yeah, you guys got to put a negative spin on everything. ",
 "No no I'm not ready, things are starting to happen. ",
 "Ok, it's forgotten. ",
 "Yeah, ok. ",
 "Hey hey, whoa come on give me a hug... "
]
```

(plus lots more...2444 lines in total)

So far I have this, but it's not making any matches.

```
# screenplay is read in from a json file
@screenplay_lines = JSON.parse(@jsonfile.read)
@text_to_find = ["relationship","negative","hug"]

@matching_results = []
@screenplay_lines.each do |line|
  if line.match(Regexp.union(@text_to_find))
    @matching_results << line
  end
end

puts "found #{@matching_results.length} matches..."
puts @matching_results
```

I'm not getting *any* hits so not sure what's not working. Plus I'm sure it's a pretty expensive process doing it this way with a large amount of data. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Regexp matching is slower than just checking if the String is included in a line of text. But this also depends on the number of keywords and the length of the lines and much more. So best would be to run at least a micro-benchmark.

```
lines = [
 "Yeah, well I wasn't looking for a long term relationship. I was on TV. ",
 "Ok, yeah, you guys got to put a negative spin on everything. ",
 "No no I'm not ready, things are starting to happen. ",
 "Ok, it's forgotten. ",
 "Yeah, ok. ",
 "Hey hey, whoa come on give me a hug... "
]
keywords = ["relationship","negative","hug"]


def find1(lines, keywords)
  regexp = Regexp.union(keywords)

  lines.select { |line| regexp.match(line) }
end


def find2(lines, keywords)
  lines.select { |line| keywords.any? { |keyword| line.include?(keyword) } }
end

def find3(lines, keywords)
  regexp = Regexp.union(keywords)

  lines.select { |line| regexp.match?(line) }
end

require 'benchmark/ips'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.compare!
  x.report('match') { find1(lines, keywords) }
  x.report('include?') { find2(lines, keywords) }
  x.report('match?') { find3(lines, keywords) }
end
```

In this setup the `include?` variant is way faster:

```
Comparison:
            include?:   288083.4 i/s
              match?:    91505.7 i/s - 3.15x  slower
               match:    65866.7 i/s - 4.37x  slower
```

Please note:

- I've moved creation of the regexp out of the loop. It does not need to be created for every line. Creation of a regexp is an expensive operation (your variant clocked in at 1/5 of the speed of the regexp outside of the loop)
- `match?` is only available in Ruby 2.4+, it is faster because it does not assign any match results (side-effect free)

I would not worry to much about performance for 2500 lines of text. If it is fast enough then stop searching for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. Great insights. The find1() method is working fine

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible solution, try this one:

[json_expressions](https://github.com/chancancode/json_expressions)

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting, but I'd like to see if a solution with less code is possible before I resort to 3rd party gems.